# Why is the following Import/Export pattern with interfaces not legal?

Tags: c#, interface, mef

I have the following class interface pattern on which I want to use MEF exporting and exporting:

```
public interface IDinosaur
{
    string Species { get; }
}

public class Pterodactyl : IDinosaur
{
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public float WingSpan { get; set; }
}

public interface ICage<in T>
{
    void Transport(T animal);
}

[Export(typeof(ICage<IDinosaur>))] // <-- This appears a problem
public class PterodactylCage : ICage<Pterodactyl>
{
    public void Transport(Pterodactyl dinosaur) { }
}

public class DinoTransportationService
{
    [Import(AllowDefault = true)]
    private ICage<IDinosaur> m_dinosaurCage = null; 
}
```

Now I would say this is legal, as the `[Export(typeof(ICage<IDinosaur>))]` indeeds exports the `ICage` of a `IDinosaur` (which happens to be a `Pterodactyl`, but this implements the dinosaur interface so that should be fine right?). However, this gives me a CompositionException. saying:

```
"The export 'PterodactylCage (ContractName=\"ICage(IDinosaur)\")' is not assignable to type 'ICage`1[[IDinosaur, MyProgramme, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'."
```

I could fix this by changing the export to:

```
[Export(typeof(ICage<Pterodactyl>))] // <-- This is ok
public class PterodactylCage : ICage<Pterodactyl>
```

And the import to:

```
[Import(AllowDefault = true)]
private ICage<Pterodactyl> m_dinosaurCage = null;
```

Except, that import now becomes far too specific, and in fact, in my case the import is in a different assembly that has never heard of Pterodactyls, so this is a bad solution. 
Why is the first example not legal, and what is the solution for this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid because (as error message says by the way) instance of `PterodactylCage` is not assignable to `ICage<IDinosaur>`:

```
ICage<IDinosaur> cage = new PterodactylCage(); // this won't compile
```

This is related to covariance\contravariance of generic interfaces, you can read what it is at many places over internet (that's broad topic to describe here).

If you had this interface definition:

```
public interface ICage<out T> // note "out" keyword
```

then that would be legal. However you cannot use out parameter as argument in your `Trasport` method, so that won't solve your problem.

A bit more on why this is illegal intuitively. Suppose that it was legal. Then you have `ICage<IDinosaur>` instance with `Tranport` method which accepts `IDinosaur`. But underlying type is `PterodactylCage` which is `ICage<Pterodactyl>`. But you can pass any instance of `IDinosaur` to `Transport` method, not just `Pterodactyl` (remember - we work with `ICage<IDinosaur>`), so that leads us to contradiction. That's why intuitively it's not legal.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation is indeed a good explanation of why the above isn't legal. Is there any alternative that make what I want to do possible though?

Comment: Well ICage<Pterodactyl> is NOT ICage<IDinosaur> in your case. If you somehow could succeed in your export and someone passed Theropods into your Transport method - it will fail at runtime. So you should revisit your logic because what you are trying to do is just wrong.

Comment: But you can implement ICage<IDinosaur> instead of ICage<Pterodactyl> and export that. You can check inside Transport method what kind of object has been passed as IDinosaur here (because it can be any Dinosaur again).